# $GLOBALS['hook_suffix'] variable empty

Tags: actions

I'm trying to implement the code to add a custom post status from my plugin, exactly as given in this tutorial: http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/wordpress-create-custom-post-status/

Now, it isn't working and after some investigation it seems the admin_footer-post.php action isn't firing. The codex page for this action hook states . . .

> admin_footer-(hookname) is triggered at the end of the  section
>   of a specific admin page, after `admin_footer` and
>   `admin_print_footer_scripts` actions.
>
> The hookname part you can get using the variable
>   $GLOBALS['hook_suffix']

. . . but that variable is empty. I've tried directly accessing $hook_suffix with no luck, and printing out the entire $GLOBALS array shows no hook_suffix anywhere.

I am very confused.

At first I thought maybe it was written for an older version of WP but there's a comment on the blog post from just 3 days ago from someone who seems to have achieved success. I've tried turning off themes and all other plugins, and just have absolutely no idea where to go from here.

What could make the $GLOBALS['hook_suffix'] variable, apparently a common enough thing in WP development, simply cease to exist on my site?

Comment: without seeing your code in context it's hard to say where you've gone wrong. if you look in `wp-admin/admin.php`, you can see where `$hook_suffix` is set in the admin bootstrap process.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you are missing the context. `$GLOBALS['hook_suffix']` is available on any action fired after `admin_init`.

Now, if you tried something like `add_action( 'admin_footer-'. $GLOBALS['hook_suffix'], 'myfunction' )` outside of any function, you are not going to get anything.

But if you do it - `add_action('admin_menu', 'do_hook_to_footer')` and put the earlier hook within the `do_hook_to_footer` function, it will work.

Or, better you try like this -

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: WPSE(#152404) $hook_suffix Test Plugin */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hook_that' );
function hook_that()
{
    add_action( "admin_footer-{$GLOBALS['hook_suffix']}", 'test_that' );
}
function test_that()
{
    echo "<h1>I AM HOOKED TO <code>admin_footer-{$GLOBALS['hook_suffix']}</code></h1>";
}
```

Comment: seems like we edited the same example to your answer at the same time. If you would like to "role back", simply click on the timestamp above my avatar and make it undone.

Comment: Your example is much cleaner and includes the example i was going to add. It should stay :)

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I tried just replacing my plugin code with the above exactly. Resulted in no message displayed and this notice:

"Notice: Undefined index: hook_suffix in blah blah..."

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I move my Wp List table to the frontend
**Notice: Undefined index: hook_suffix in ..../wp-admin/includes/class-wp-screen.php on line 213**

I fixed it by replacing

```
$id = $GLOBALS['hook_suffix'];
```

with

```
$id = isset($GLOBALS['hook_suffix']) ? $GLOBALS['hook_suffix'] : "";
```

Comment: Be aware that your change is likely to get overwritten by a future WordPress release at some point. Also, you won't be able to install a new version of WordPress with your plugins and themes. It's best to fix the source of the issue rather than the symptom. As for what the source is, I have no idea! I'm trying to work it out myself!  